# Unable to get response in JSON format after aggregation in WSO2 ESB

Tags: json, wso2, response, esb, wso2-esb

I have a proxy service to search a user in multiple systems and should return the combined responses in JSON format.I get the responses combined but instead of getting it in JSON format I get the responses in XML format.
I can see JSON responses in WSO2 server logs as below:

```
[2016-07-19 07:26:58,249]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addr
essing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:895c4303-6de5-49
88-a4d1-c06275582841, Direction: response, Component = Application2, Payload: {
"findUsers":[
{"id":"20","add_state":"0","remove_state":"0","supervisor_id_name":"","idc_id":"
3","backup_supervisor_name":"","backup_supervisor":"","business_unit_id":"","com
pany":"companyb","creation_date":"2016-05-11 18:02:42.0","deletion_date":"","dep
artment":"922","display_name":"Kevin Mollo (companyb)","email_address":"Kevin.Mo
llo@companyb.com","exception_count":"","first_name":"Kevin","is_terminated":"Fal
se","job_status":"Active","last_name":"Mollo","legacy_employee_id":"171352","sup
ervisor_id":"","termination_date":"","title":"Broadband Technician","unique_id":
"9000070","user_id":"user71","violation_count":""}
]
}
[2016-07-19 07:26:58,888]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addr
essing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:0cee9dc3-b6e6-48
81-9bdd-a89ec22999a7, Direction: response, Component = Application1, Payload: {"vi
ewableIdentityAttributes":{"Email":"Kevin.Mollo@companyb.com","cn":"Kevin Mollo"
,"Last Name":"Mollo","First Name":"Kevin"},"assignedRoles":[],"listAttributes":[
"First Name","Last Name","Email","cn"]}
```

However, I don't get response in JSON format after calling the proxy url.
Below is my ESB configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="SPRSAPproxy"
       transports="http,https"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log/>
         <clone>
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <property name="Application" value="Application1"/>
                  <property name="messageType"
                            value="application/xacml+json"
                            scope="axis2"
                            type="STRING"/>
                  <property name="Authorization"
                            expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('username:password'))"
                            scope="transport"/>
                  <send>
                     <endpoint>
                        <address uri="http://hostname1:8080/identityiq/rest/identities/9000070"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </send>
               </sequence>
            </target>
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <property name="Application" value="Application2"/>
                  <property name="messageType"
                            value="application/json"
                            scope="axis2"
                            type="STRING"/>
                  <send>
                     <endpoint>
                        <address uri="http://hostname2:8080/aveksa/command.submit?cmd=findUsers&amp;format=json&amp;unique_id=9000070"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </send>
               </sequence>
            </target>
         </clone>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full" description="">
            <property name="Component" expression="get-property('Application')"/>
         </log>
         <aggregate>
            <completeCondition>
               <messageCount min="2"/>
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete expression="/">
               <property name="messageType"
                         value="application/xacml+json"
                         scope="axis2"
                         type="STRING"
                         description="messageType"/>
               <enrich>
                  <source clone="true" xpath="/"/>
                  <target type="body"/>
               </enrich>
               <send/>
            </onComplete>
         </aggregate>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence>
         <log level="full" category="WARN"/>
      </faultSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

I get the response as below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><jsonObject><findUsers><id>20</id><add_state>0</add_state><remove_state>0</remove_state><supervisor_id_name></supervisor_id_name><idc_id>3</idc_id><backup_supervisor_name></backup_supervisor_name><backup_supervisor></backup_supervisor><business_unit_id></business_unit_id><company>companyb</company><creation_date>2016-05-11 18:02:42.0</creation_date><deletion_date></deletion_date><department>922</department><display_name>Kevin Mollo (companyb)</display_name><email_address>Kevin.Mollo@companyb.com</email_address><exception_count></exception_count><first_name>Kevin</first_name><is_terminated>False</is_terminated><job_status>Active</job_status><last_name>Mollo</last_name><legacy_employee_id>171352</legacy_employee_id><supervisor_id></supervisor_id><termination_date></termination_date><title>Broadband Technician</title><unique_id>9000070</unique_id><user_id>user71</user_id><violation_count></violation_count></findUsers></jsonObject><soapenv:Envelope><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><jsonObject><viewableIdentityAttributes><Email>Kevin.Mollo@companyb.com</Email><cn>Kevin Mollo</cn><Last Name>Mollo</Last Name><First Name>Kevin</First Name></viewableIdentityAttributes><listAttributes>First Name</listAttributes><listAttributes>Last Name</listAttributes><listAttributes>Email</listAttributes><listAttributes>cn</listAttributes></jsonObject></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please let me know how I can get the JSON response.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the messageType to application/json instead of application/xacml+json in outSequence and try.

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING" description="messageType"/>
```

Also there is no application/xacml+json message formatters and message builders shipped with WSO2 ESB by default. If you need to use these formats you have to write your own formatters and builders and configure them in axis2.xml file.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this already but I get error in my server and don't get any response: Error is :
[2016-07-20 13:33:06,363] ERROR - JsonUtil #writeAsJson. Could not convert OMEle
ment to JSON. Invalid XML payload. Error>>> Unexpected character '>' (code 62) e
xpected '='
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,147]
[2016-07-20 13:33:06,363] ERROR - PassThroughHttpSender Failed to submit the res
ponse
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Could not write JSON stream.
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:22
1)

Comment: Seems like the message cannot be validated as an OMElement. Can you try enabling wire logs and post here to verify what is the payload received from the backend. To enable wirelogs follow : http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html

Comment: Please click on the below link to see server response :
[Server Response](http://imgur.com/a/zzyLm)

Comment: I have attached the link to the snapshot in the comment above. Could you please check it and let me know where is the issue. Thank you..